# Spark-submit command options --num-executors issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I have following spark configuration :

**1 Master and 2 Workers**

- Each worker has **88 Cores** , hence **total no. of cores 176**
- Each worker has **502 GB** memory , so **total memory available is 1004 GB**

now I want to run 40 executors so that all the cores will not be used.

I am running below command for same.

```
./spark-submit --class com.sample.Transformation --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5001 --num-executors=40 --executor-cores=1 --executor-memory=5G --master spark://10.180.181.41:7077 "/MyProject/Transformation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" > /MyProject/logs/logs12.txt
```

Here i have sepcified `--num-executors=40` still **176** executors has been created.

In same command When I changed `--executor-cores=3`it created **176/3 = 58** executors and **174 cores** are used.

So it seems **--num-executors** value is not being considered in the command.

I want to understand why such behaviour of command and what can be resolution for same.

**EDIT:**

I am not using **standalone mode** here.

Comment: @user8371915 I will try the formulae given in the referenced question, however that question is for standalone mode and I am not using standalone mode in my case.

Comment: @user8371915 Thank for pointing it out, it worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. And at least the code in the question, uses standalone mode. `spark://...` is standalone master URL.